# hiberater @filter parameters enum type

Tags: java, hibernate, filter

How to set @filter parameter type as enum in hibernate?

Hibernate version 5.3.x

```
@FilterDef(name = "my_filter", parameters = {
@ParamDef(name = "status", type = "what should be here? ") 
})
@Filter(name = "my_filter", condition = "status = :status")
@Entity
public class MyEntity{
  ....
  private MyStatus status;
  ....

}
```

the enum

```
public enum MyStatus{
   STATUS1,STATUS2
}
```

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/de-DE/html/filters.html  `session.enableFilter("myFilter").setParameter("myFilterParam", "some-value");`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I cannot find anything about enum type.

Comment: enum isn't different from anything else

Comment: @XtremeBaumer so, ParamDef(name = "status", type = "what should be here? ")

Comment: `MyStatus`.....

Comment: @XtremeBaumer not working .

Comment: Why? Have you enabled the filter?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer bug! cannot run. org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Undefined filter parameter . It's working when I use other attribute(int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Filter definition on class:

```
@FilterDef(name = "my_filter", parameters = {
     @ParamDef(name = "state", type = "string") 
     })
@Filter(name = "my_filter", condition = "status = :status")
@Entity
public class MyEntity{
  ....
  private MyStatus status;
  ....

}
```

enable filter:

```
session.enableFilter("my_filter").setParameter("state", MySatus.STATUS1.toString());
```